# Adding Cookies to Language Changer

Tags: javascript, api, cookies, mootools

I'm trying to add a little Language changer for my site. I'd like it to save the language using cookies.

How can this code be modified to achieve this goal?

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAMt9YZQaG_wbfmb2826e_wBTPUDO5TVHJS-HZdrhJpqnB5yZcfRQFObTd1-bPphEIY11228Z78VhA6A"></script>
    <script src="http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/mootools-1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set the original/default language
        var lang = "en";
        var currentClass = "currentLang";

        // Load the language lib
        google.load("language",1);

        // When the DOM is ready....
        window.addEvent("domready",function(){
            // Retrieve the DIV to be translated.
            var translateDiv = document.id("languageBlock");
            // Define a function to switch from the currentlanguage to another
            var callback = function(result) {
                if(result.translation) {
                    translateDiv.set("html",result.translation);
                }
            };
            // Add a click listener to update the DIV
            $$("#languages a").addEvent("click",function(e) {
                // Stop the event
                if(e) e.stop();
                // Get the "to" language
                var toLang = this.get("rel");
                // Set the translation into motion
                google.language.translate(translateDiv.get("html"),lang,toLang,callback);
                // Set the new language
                lang = toLang;
                // Add class to current
                this.getSiblings().removeClass(currentClass);
                this.addClass(currentClass);
            });
        });

    </script>

<div id="languages"><p>
        <a href="?lang=en" rel="en">English</a> / <a href="?lang=es" rel="es">Spanish</a> 
    </p></div>

    <div id="languageBlock">
        <p>Lights go out and I can't be saved <br />
        Tides that I tried to swim against  <br />
        Brought me down upon my knees  <br />
        Oh I beg, I beg and plead </p>

        <p>Singin', come out if things aren't said  <br />
        Shoot an apple off my head  <br />
        And a, trouble that can't be named  <br />
        Tigers waitin' to be tamed </p>

        <p>Singing, yooooooooooooo ohhhhhh  <br />
        Yoooooooooooo ohhhhhh </p>

        <p>Home, home, where I wanted to go <br /> 
        Home, home, where I wanted to go  <br />
        Home, home, where I wanted to go  <br />
        Home, home, where I wanted to go</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use cookies? HTML5's new [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) would make the job much easier.
Also, you're using <a> links to redirect them to a translated page. If they're already on http://foo.bar/?lang=en and they clicked the Spanish link, it'd take them to http://foo.bar/?lang=en?lang=es as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using MooTools. Consider using the [MooTools cookie functionality](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Cookie):

Place this when you're done switching the language in your link click event handler:

```
// Add class to current
this.getSiblings().removeClass(currentClass);
this.addClass(currentClass);

//now set the cookie
var myCookie = Cookie.write('userLang', toLang);
```

When you want to read the cookie, perhaps on page load (or whichever event you like):

```
alert('This user has their language set to: ' + Cookie.read('userLang'));
```

Comment: Well, one problem it still doesn't save the actual language.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't save"? `Cookie.write` saves the value. It saves that choice into the cookie. Do you mean that it doesn't auto-choose the previously-chosen language? If that's the case, then see my 2nd code snippet: "read the cookie....whichever event you like". Set your HTML elements based on this.

Comment: When i click Spanish and then refresh. The Language is back to English. I need it too stay ES.